# MapStruct cant find method annotated with @Named#value when @Context is used

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm using MapStruct version 1.4.2, Java 17 and Spring-boot 3.1.0.
Here I'm trying to use some fields in the source to get a value from a cache which is passed using @Context.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UrlMapper.class, UserDataCache.class})
public interface PackageMapper { 
    PackageMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PackageMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "childClientId", source = "childClientId", defaultValue = "0")
    @Mapping(target = "userData", source = "parcel", qualifiedByName = "userDataTestMapping")
    Client clientFrom(ParcelDto parcel);

    @Named("userDataTestMapping")
    default UserData clientDataFrom(ParcelDto parcel, @Context UserDataCache userDataCache) {
        return userDataCache.getUserDetails(parcel.getClientId(), parcel.getChildClientId());
    }

}

public class UserDataCache {
  private final Cache<String, UserData> userDataCache;

  public UserData getUserDetails(Integer clientId, Integer childClientId) {
    String key = String.format("%d_%d", clientId, childClientId);
    return clientsDataCache.getIfPresent(key);
  }

}

public class ParcelDto { 
    @JsonProperty("clientId")
    private String clientId;
    
    @JsonProperty("childClientId")
    private String childClientId;
}

public class PackageProgress { 
    private Sender sender;
}

public class Sender {
    private Client client;
}

public class Client {
    private Integer childClientId;
    private UserData userData;
}
```

But end up having below error where it cant resolve the `@Named` method. If I remove the `@Context` parameter I no longer have the error. What could be the reason not being able to use `@Context` here?
Is there an alternative to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to rewrite `Client clientFrom(ParcelDto parcel)` adding `@Context` parameter so mapstruct is able to match call